# Issues when increasing Azure Instance Count

Tags: azure, count, instance, sitefinity

I'm having issues with one of our client's websites.  We recently increased the instance count from 1 to 2.  Now the site is much more responsive, but it's behaving very strangely.  The website uses the Sitefinity CMS.  When a content update is made, it does not show up when others view it.  From what I've read, adding an instance creates a load balanced environment.  Is that really what's happening?  If so, how can I access each instance individually?  I need to tell Sitefinity what addresses are part of the load balanced environment, from what I can tell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What azure service are you using? Website, VM, Cloud Service?

Comment: Do you have a license for the LoadBalancing module? You would need that so that the cache is invalidated properly between the different nodes of the LB environment. 

AFAIK Sitefinity automatically configures the LB module if it is inside Azure Cloud Service, but if you are using Azure VMs then you have to manually add the necessary LB config in the Sitefinity's Advanced settings